# What's the fastest way to get online computers

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a function which returns all Online Computers in our network, so I can do stuff like this:

```
Get-OnlineComputers | % { get-process -computername $_ }
```

Now I basically got my function ready, but it's taking way too long.
I want to only return Computers which have WinRM active, but I also want to provide the option to get every computer even those which haven't got WinRM set up (switch parameter).

This is my function. first it creates a pssession to the domaincontroller, to get all computers in our LAN. then foreach computer, it will test if they have WinRM active or if they accept ping. if so, it  gets returned.

```
$session = New-PSSession Domaincontroller
$computers = Invoke-Command -Session $session { Get-ADComputer -filter * } | select -ExpandProperty Name

$computers | % {
    if ($IncludeNoWinRM.IsPresent) 
    {
        $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
        $ping = Test-NetConnection $_ 
        if ($ping.PingSucceeded -eq 'True') 
        {
            $_
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
        $WinRM = Test-WSMan $_
        if ($WinRM)
        {
            $_
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the best way I can go to check my online computers? Does anyone have a faster and better idea?

Thanks!

Comment: i would first test if they accept a ping. then you know if they are online and if yes you can check for WinRM. i might be wrong but maybe this speeds it up

Comment: oops - why did I get a downvote? What can I improve in my question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very Quick Solution is using the `-Quiet` Parameter of the `Test-Connection` cmdlet:

so for example:

```
$ping = Test-Connection "Computer" -Quiet -Count 1
if ($ping)
{
"Online"
}
     else
     {
     "Offline"
     }
```

if it's not enough fast for you, you can use the `Send` Method of the `System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping`

here's a sample function:

```
Function Test-Ping
{
Param($computer = "127.0.0.1")
  $ping = new-object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
  Try
  {
  [void]$ping.send($computer,1)
  $Online = $true
  }

  Catch
  {
    $Online = $False
  }

  Return $Online
}
```

Regarding execute it on multiple computers, I suggest using RunSpaces, as it's the fastest Multithreading you can get with PowerShell,

For more information see:

[Runspaces vs Jobs](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjRkqq4gd3QAhVaOMAKHXyRD_oQFggpMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn-powershell.net%2F2012%2F05%2F13%2Fusing-background-runspaces-instead-of-psjobs-for-better-performance%2F&usg=AFQjCNExaaBOnhABZ9Keqb-kejMT2HrSbQ)

[Basic Runspaces implemenation](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/26/beginning-use-of-powershell-runspaces-part-1/)

Comment: very nice. i'll try your suggestions and accept this as an answer. I'd give you another +1 if I could for telling me about RunSpaces. very interesting!

Comment: @simons i'd rather go with Posh-RSJob, since it handles all the pain with runspaces, then try to implement runspaces.

Answer (score 1):

Boe Prox (master of runspaces) has written a function which is available from the Powershell Gallery. I've linked the script below.

He uses many of the answers already given to achieve the simultaneous examination of 100s of computers by name.  The script gets WMI network information if test-connection succeeds.  It should be fairly easy to adapt to get any other information you want, or just return the result of the test-connection.

The script actually uses runspace pools rather than straight runspaces to limit the amount of simultaneous threads that your loop can spawn.

Boe also wrote the PoSH-RSJob module already referenced.  This script will achieve what you want in native PoSH without having to install his module.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Speedy-Network-Information-5b1406fb